# I have an error runing a while loop in python

Tags: python

I am begineer at coding in python and i am trying to create a simple calculator.I want the code to repeat it self an quit when i type in "q".But the output gave an error ""

Here is the code

```
while True:
    nums=float(input('Enter numbers for calculations'))
    if str(nums) == 'q':
        break
    operation.append(nums)
```

Here is the error it gave:

```
 * nums=float(input('Enter numbers for calculations'))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'q'*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int

Comment: Of course, you're converting whatever you input to a float. So if you input `'q'`, it will try to convert it to a float, which fails. Try checking for `'q'` before converting to a float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the input() is already a string by definition if you put a "float" inside it, it will turn it into a string right away so:

```
while True:
    x= input('Enter numbers for calculations')
    if x == 'q':
        break
print(x)
```

will make it repeat itself and when you type q it will stop